# Spliting a line of text to get two variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm quite lost with this one, im currently making a program that gets an input from a .txt document, the first line says: "From:0 To:4", and my goal is to get the "0" and "4" values.

This is what im currently doing:

```
with open('graph.txt') as matrix:  
    linea = matrix.readlines()  
    for line in linea:  
         if line.startswith('From:'):  
             start = line.rsplit(':')[-1].strip() 
             start= int(start,10)                      
         elif line.__contains__('To:'):  
              end = line.split(':')[-1].strip()  
              end = int(end,10)
```

I made it this way because before the "from:" and "to:" were in two different lines, but I needed to set them in the same one. The prolem righ now is that whenever i run the code I got "NameError: name 'end' is not defined".

Comment: First of all, don't call `__contains__`, do `if 'To:' in line:`. You very rarely have to call methods with two underscores.

Comment: So all the lines in your file are `From:x To:y` ? Or is there a possibility of any other formatting?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest flexible way is to use a regex:

```
import re

with open('graph.txt') as matrix:
    for line in matrix: 
        from_, to = re.findall(r':(\d+)', line)
```

This fetches the two numeric data to two variables `from_` and `to`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is the `elif` -- since the `if` block executes, `elif` never does, so `end` never gets set. Changing `elif` to `if` will result in both `if` blocks executing, so both variables get set.

You'll end up with a bit of repeated code, though, which is frowned upon (DRY)

@Boris's comment is important, too, you don't have to call `__contains__`

I came up with a different regex than Austin's, which splits on spaces and colons to tokenize the line:

```py
import re
with open('matrix.txt') as matrix:
    linea = matrix.readlines()
    for line in linea:
        split = re.split('\s|:', line)
        start, end = (split[1], split[3])
        print(f"{start} {end}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should regex to extract all possible numbers from the string. The code below should work irrespective of any string around the numbers.

```
import re

with open('graph.txt') as matrix:
    for line in matrix:
        start, end = re.findall(r'(\d+)', line)
        print(start)
        print(end)
```

So if the file looks like:

```
From:  0 To:  4
From:0 To:   4
From:  123To:  456
From 12 to 34
```

The output will be

```
0
4
0
4
123
456
12
34
```

As you can see, all numbers were extracted, irrespective of the format of the string.

Answer (score -1):

### Oneliner

```py
(_, begin), (_, end) = list(map(lambda s: s.split(":"), line.split()))
```

First I'm splitting the line in two using the builtin through the built in [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).  Next I'm making use of the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function to apply a [`lambda`](https://needlink.com) which further splits the line into four stages, again using the `split` function of strings in python.  Lastly the values are stored as `begin` and `end` using [`tuple unpacking`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Hope this didn't go over your head and helps you.

Answer (score -2):

The code below will read what you want.

```
with open('graph.txt') as matrix:  
    linea = matrix.readlines()  
    for line in linea:  
        if line.startswith('From:'):  
            start = line.split('From:')
            #start= int(start,10)
            print(start)
            for a in start:
                if a.__contains__('To:'):
                    b = a.split('To:')
                    print(b[0].strip(),b[1].strip())
```

And a second option which is similar to your code:

```
with open('graph.txt') as matrix:  
    linea = matrix.readlines()

    for line in linea:
        d = line.split(' ')
        print(d)
        for elm in d:
            if elm.__contains__('From:'):
                print(elm.split(':')[-1].strip())
            elif elm.__contains__('To:'):
                print(elm.split(':')[-1].strip())
```

Comment: If the file look like this.

From:0 To:4 From:1 To:5

The first block of code return
0 4
1 5

The second block of codes return
0
4
1
5
My code return correct answer, I don't see what's wrong with that.